# How to access AWS S3 bucket from digital ocean server without access key and secret key

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean

We are planning to continuously generate logs moving from the digital ocean Server to AWS S3 Bucket without access key and secret key

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access S3 like that